# Passing a reference into a procedural macro in Rust

Tags: c++, rust, macros, metaprogramming

Let's take just as an example, calculating the median of a sequence of integers at compile time.

I have implemented it both in C++ and in Rust.

C++: https://gist.github.com/jymchng/bf527d68a9a352cf43078cad124673ea
Rust: https://github.com/jymchng/median-proc-macro/blob/master/crates/median-pm-core/src/lib.rs#L9

In C++, I am able to first instantiate an array, then pass the array as a reference into the overloaded `median` function and it works. Like so:

```
std::array<int, 5> arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
auto median_seven = median<5>(arr1);
```

However, in Rust, I cannot think of anyway to do that. Like so:

```
let my_vec = vec![1,2,3,4,5];
let median = median!(&my_vec);
```

When I tried doing that, I get a `syn::Ident` with value `"my_vec"`.

Generally, what is the mechanism/idiom to pass reference/value into the procedural macro and let the macro treats them as reference/value respectively?

Comment: The C++ function is not evaluated at compile time unless it is in a `constexpr` context or using `consteval`.

Comment: You're [ignoring all `Punct`](https://github.com/jymchng/median-proc-macro/blob/master/crates/median-pm-core/src/implement.rs#L21) which is where that `&` for the reference goes.

Comment: To be clear, macros cannot access values, even `const` values, only literals passed to them. Macros work on tokens. The equivalent to `constexpr` in C++, which works on values, is `const fn`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yeah, I think that C++ function is evaluated at compile time because functions marked by `constexpr` cannot call other non-constant functions. I called `std::sort` within, and each `median` is directly instantiated without being used in a non-constant function in `int main()`

Comment: @ChayimFriedman How would you explain `std::array<int, 5> arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; auto median_seven = median<5>(arr1);` works and yet we cannot make something similar work in Rust?

Comment: *and yet we cannot make something similar work in Rust?* -- Ask the people who maintain the Rust language.  As for C++, `constexpr` works for `std::array`.

Comment: Also, just as an aside, why are you using `vec![]` in Rust, but `std::array` in C++? The correct type to use to compare would be `[T; N]`. And the reason it doesn't work is because Rust's `slice::sort` isn't `const`. When it get's there, you'll be able to sort slices at compile-time.

Comment: C++'s `constexpr` is indeed more advanced than Rust's `const` and allows for more (it's also much older, though). Rust's `const` is advancing, though, and allows more in each release. For your code to work, however, there are two big `const` features that are missing and perhaps will be for a long time, because there are unresolved questions with them (C++ allows both): const allocation, for allocating `Vec` at compile-time (this is not necessary, though, and not used in your C++ version: you can use arrays (`[T; N]`)), and const mutable references, for `<[T]>::sort()`.

Comment: Actually, three: `<[T]>::sort()` also requires const traits.

Comment: And as you said, despite being `constexpr`, your code is executed at runtime in C++.

Comment: @PatientPenguin  @ChayimFriedman Sure, I could use [u64; N] as the fair comparison but it wouldn't change my question which is how am I supposed to make `let my_arr = [1, 2, 3]; median!(&my_arr);` works.

Comment: I think the crux of the matter is how do I expand the tokens that such I can take in a reference of an array, compute its median at compile time and return to the caller via a procedural (or maybe even a declarative macro or a mix of both) macro.

Comment: @Jim You cannot do that with a macro via a reference (i.e. `my_macro!(&some_array)`). To do it with a macro it would have to see the values directly (i.e. `my_macro!([1, 2, 3, 4])`).

Comment: Why do you need this? What's your actual usecase? Because passing a reference (a runtime object) into a proc macro (a compile time thing) and trying to evaluate it is a weird request, so I kind of feel like this is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 3):

Macros cannot be used for this. However, `const fn`s can. Macros turn syntax into other syntax at compile time; `const fn`s turn values into other values at compile time (if invoked from a const context).

Currently, `const fn` capabilities are fairly limited (notably, anything involving calling trait functions cannot be used) but it is possible today to sort integers, and therefore to find the median. Here's a simple, inefficient proof of concept:

```rust
use std::mem;

const fn bubble_sort_median<const N: usize>(data: &[i32; N]) -> i32 {
    let mut data = *data;
    let median_index = N / 2;
    let mut sorted_up_to = 0;
    loop {
        // Start this pass at the end of the array.
        let Some(mut i) = data.len().checked_sub(2) else { break };
        if i < sorted_up_to {
            // Fewer than 2 elements left to sort, so they're all sorted.
            break;
        }
        while i >= sorted_up_to {
            if data[i] > data[i + 1] {
                let tmp = data[i];
                data[i] = data[i + 1];
                data[i + 1] = tmp;
            }
            let Some(ni) = i.checked_sub(1) else { break };
            i = ni;
        }
        // We have bubbled the largest element to the [sorted_up_to] position
        sorted_up_to += 1;
    }
    
    // Compute median now that enough of the array has been sorted that the
    // median is located at the middle.
    if data.len() % 2 == 0 {
        (data[median_index - 1] + data[median_index]) / 2
    } else {
        data[median_index]
    }
}

#[test]
fn tests() {
    // Const evaluation
    const INPUT: [i32; 5] = [1,2,3,4,5];
    const MEDIAN: i32 = bubble_sort_median(&INPUT);
    assert_eq!(MEDIAN, 3);
    
    // Some more test cases for the algorithm (not compile-time)
    assert_eq!(bubble_sort_median(&[9, 9, 2, 2, 1]), 2);
    assert_eq!(bubble_sort_median(&[9, 4, 2, 2, 9, 1]), 3);
}
```

We all hope that in future Rust versions, it will be possible to write more general and more straightforward `const fn` code (e.g. using `for` loops in this function, and making it generic over `T: Ord`).

And if you actually want to compute the median, it would be better to implement [quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) rather than bubble sort.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I think this is a beautiful answer.